# Losing php posted string variable information after executing top.location.href

Tags: php, javascript, post, facebook-authentication

The following code involves authenticating Facebook app users with a script that is triggered by a php form event. I am posting a string through an HTML form with the following code:

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="test.php" method="post">
    <input name="message" type="text" value=""><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"/><br/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The code for test.php is:

```
<html>
    <head xmlns:testapp="https://apps.facebook.com/testapp/ns#">
        <title>World Centric</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    $app_id = "191622610935428";
    $my_url = "http://www.thepropagator.com/facebook/testapp";
    $string1 = $_POST["message"];
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['string']=$string1;
    echo $string1;
    $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

    if(empty($code)) 
    {
        $dialog_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
            . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) 
            . "&scope=email,publish_actions";
        echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
        echo "string1".$string1;
    }
   $string1 = $_SESSION['string'];
    echo $string1;
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

When text.php initially executes is echos the string posted from the form

```
$string1 = $_POST["message"];
```

However after the line:

```
echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
```

Is executed the variable $string1 comes up empty. I need to retain this information after the above line is executed. Can any suggest how I might accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

When you change the href like that in Javascript, it causes the new URL to be loaded via 'GET'. if you need to preserve variables like that, you'll have to pass them in the new url's query string, or store them elsewhere, such as in a cookie or a server-side session.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I believe you are right but I'm having trouble implementing the solution. I have edited my code alterations in the original block above but I am still having the same problem with losing information. Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?