# PHP session will retain text but not a posted variable value

Tags: php, session, variables, format

The following code involves authenticating Facebook app users with a script that is triggered by a php form event. I am posting a string through an HTML form with the following code:

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="test.php" method="post">
    <input name="message" type="text" value=""><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"/><br/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The code for test.php is:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html>
   <head xmlns:worldcentric="https://apps.facebook.com/testapp/ns#">
     <title>Test App</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <?php
    $app_id = "191622610935428";
    $my_url = "http://www.thepropagator.com/facebook/testapp/test1.php";
    $string1 = (string)$_POST["message"];
    $_SESSION['str'] = $string1;
   // $string2 = "teststring";
   // $_SESSION['str'] = $string2;

  $code = $_REQUEST["code"];
  if(empty($code)) {
    $dialog_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
    . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&scope=email,publish_actions";
    echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
  }

$string3 = $_SESSION['str'];
echo $string3;
   ?>
   </body>
 </html>
```

For the code above the information I'm trying to store in

```
$_SESSION['str']
```

Is not being preserved. However when I replace the lines

```
    $string1 = (string)$_POST["message"];
    $_SESSION['str'] = $string1;
```

With the commented out lines:

```
    $string2 = "teststring";
    $_SESSION['str'] = $string2;
```

The text "teststring" does get passed along. As you can see I tried casting $_POST["message"] to a string but it doesn't work either way. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Losing php posted string variable information after executing top.location.href](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875154/losing-php-posted-string-variable-information-after-executing-top-location-href)

Comment: This is a more rigorously exposited  problem from the same project, hence the similarities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line:

```
echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
```

Was causing the script to execute over again from the top. There were two problems with this one was that I was storing my information in a regular variable that was getting erased when the script started over, the fix for that was to use a session variable. Theo other problem was than when the script started over and read the line:

```
$string1 = (string)$_POST["message"];
```

There was not post this time around so it was erasing the variable. I fixed this by replacing the line above with the following:

if (empty($_SESSION['string']) )
  $_SESSION['string']=$_POST["message"];

if (empty($_SESSION['string']) )
  $_SESSION['string']=$_POST["message"];

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to cast as string, as by default PHP will treat it as a string.

The only thing I can think is, are you sure `$_POST['message']` holds something? Echo it to make sure its not empty.

Try something like this:

```
$_SESSION['str'] = (empty($_POST['message'])) ? "empty" : $_POST['message'];
```

Also, in your HTML,

```
<input name="message" type="text" value="">
```

You haven't closed the input tag.

Comment: I have tried the echo test. The data is getting through from the form.